# Testing redux saga with dynamic payloads from requests

Tags: testing, redux-saga, redux-saga-test-plan

I'm trying to understand tests with redux-saga-test-plan, but I'm kinda stuck with dynamic payloads.

Here's my saga:

```
function* getCheapCars() {
    try {
        const response = yield call(fetch, '/api/home')
        const cars = yield call([response, response.json])
        yield put({ type: types.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS, cars })
    } catch (error) {
        yield put({ type: types.FETCH_DATA_ERROR, error })
    }
}
```

And here is the test:

```
it('just works!', () => {
    return expectSaga(saga)
        .take('FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS')
        .put({ type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS', cars })
        .dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS', cars })
        .run()
})
```

I'm probably wrong (I'm completely new to saga), but how to get dynamic payloads from request - in this case it's cars. Cars represent an array of multiple "posts" with title, slug, id and many other fields. Should I just create a fake object with exact same fields?

And I would need a little help with testing withReducer, basically here's the same saga and this test pass but it shouldn't. Because I don't expect an empty array of items, but array with length of 4 (cars).

```
it('just works!', async () => {
   const { storeState } = await expectSaga(saga)
     .withReducer(reducer)
     .run()

   expect(storeState).toEqual({
     loading: false,
     error: null,
     items: []
   })
})
```

Is there something I just don't get? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What i understood in saga testing with redux-saga-test-plan is that we should mock our api call and select call.

Mock is done via provide method, so real api will not be called.

```
const mockResponse = []; // your api response 
it('getCheapCars test', () => expectSaga(getCheapCars)
  .provide([
    [call(fetch, '/api/home'), mockResponse],
  ])
  .put({ type: types.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS, cars: mockResponse })
  .run())
```